# analyze user input c++

Tags: c++, char

I want to make program which analyzes every letter of the text which has been written by the user of the program. So for example, someone types "hello there". Is there a way to put all these letters in some array? For example, myArray[0]=h, myArray[1]=e,...
Thank you

Comment: Have you tried `cin.read()`? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `std::string` just like an array, but it's dynamic, knows its size, and is a lot more flexible.

```
//string is like a dynamic array of characters
std::string input; 

//get a whole line of input from stdin and store it
std::getline (std::cin, input); 

//you can manipulate it like an array, among other things
input [0] = 'i'; //now "iello there"
```

For a complete reference on `std::string`, see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Comment: But isn't std::string of const char*? Or is that just C

Comment: @ColeJohnson, Internally, `std::string` has a `char *`, which points to an area on the heap that it maintains for you. It encapsulates access through safer methods, such as resizing the array to fit your line of input, rather than possibly overrun a buffer.

Comment: @ColeJohnson and neither std::string not C-style strings are const.

Comment: Then why have I seen this in places: "typedef const char* string;"

Comment: @ColeJohnson, That should be code-specific. It's just saying that `string` (not `std::string`) will be an alias for `const char *`. That's just the way that code was designed, probably to make it more intuitive in C, as you can say `string s = "hi";`.

Comment: @ColeJohnson String literals have type `char*` in C and C++ for legacy reasons. It's not allowed to modify them, so it's a good practice to point to them using `const char*`. `std::string` is another pair of shoes, it's  C++-specific and more flexible. You can get a `const char*` out of it using `c_str()` if you need to.

Comment: @Kos, Thanks for the alternate explanation. I didn't think of those missing parts. However, string literals have the type `const char[]` in C++. Otherwise, this wouldn't work: http://ideone.com/aUeGD